# Auto Approval process causing NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process

Tags: apex, approval-process

I have an approval process which auto approves the record once an entry criteria is satisfied. I am submitting record for approval process via trigger. But it throws an error:

> Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found.:

If I change the approval process and send the record for approval to a user instead of auto approving it, Approval process works as expected when a record is submitted for approval via trigger.